# how to get copy the latest record row ssis

Tags: ssis

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZY3V.png)

The output table shoould be populated with the row with least Aging(sec) value for each of the TicketNO.

Need help on designing the ssis package for this.

Explanation:

I have a table(Table A) with ticket details and I want to populate another table (Table B) with data from Table A.

Now in Table A, one ticket has multiple instances. To identify the latest row for each ticket I am using a derived column(Column Age) where I calculate the difference between row created time and system datetime.

In Table B, I want the data to update/insert from Table A.If ticket number is already present in Table B, Update data from Table A from the row which has the least value in Col Age for that ticket number; else insert the row from Table A the ticket number which has least value in Col Age for that ticket number.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your less explained question is that you are looking for populate the most recent tickets to output table.

If this is true then you can add derived column in your input set where you can calculate the time of the ticket (may be inserted date of the ticket) and do the order by asc.

### Edit

As you updated the question. Create one stored procedure to populate data from table a table b and use merge statement for inserting new or updating existing data. Google for merge statement in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But I have updated the question with more details...hope this helps.